# Magento iterator fatal error

Tags: php, magento, magento2, fatal-error

I have installed Magento 2.2.2 with XAMPP 5.0.27 but when I access my store's address (`localhost/magento`) it shows a 404/Not Found error and the admin login is not opening.

When I reload this page its show iterator fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Iterator' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\FileIterator.php
>   on line 16

Comment: try to see the log file inside var/log, also try to reinstall magento again

Comment: Try to restart Apache and Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.2 [requires, at minimum, PHP 7.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).  You're using an older version of PHP that doesn't have the standard library's `Iterator` interface installed, so you need to upgrade to a newer version of PHP.